# Trig Integral, Product to Sum

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to solve the integral $\displaystyle\int\sin(2x)\sin(4x)\text{d}x$. Here's my attempt:

$$\int\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x-4x)-\cos(2x+4x))\text{d}x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\cos(-2x)\text{d}x-\frac{1}{2}\int\cos(6x)\text{d}x$$
$$\text{Let u = 2x and v = 6x}$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\int\cos(u)\text{d}u-\frac{1}{12}\int\cos(v)\text{d}v$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\sin(u)-\frac{1}{12}\sin(v)$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)-\frac{1}{12}\sin(6x)+C$$

But the answer is:

$$\frac{\sin^3(2x)}{3} + C$$

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's the formula for $\sin(3a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're equivalent. You'd get their answer with $u=\sin 2x$ since $\sin 4x=2\sin 2x\cos 2x$.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if they were equivalent or not.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't go wrong. You can check it's the same function, usuing the trig formula (once taught in high school):
$$\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x, $$
so $\sin 6x=\dotsm$